# I can't get my second django view to validate the post request after the first view redirects

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm having issue where i want the second view where it validates if a "post" request is validated, execute the set of code. Here's an example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import loader
from django.core.mail import send_mail, mail_admins
from .forms import Register
# Importing Models
from .models import Users
# Create your views here.

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms = Register(request.POST)

        if forms.is_valid():
            f_name = forms.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            l_name = forms.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            em = forms.cleaned_data["email"]
            num = forms.cleaned_data["phone"]
            user = Users(
                first_name=f_name,
                last_name=l_name,
                email=em,
                phone=num
                )
            user.save()
            request.session['f_name'] = f_name
            request.session['status'] = True
            request.session['email'] = em
            return redirect('success')
            
        
        else:
            forms = Register()
    
    forms = Register()
    title = "Join now"
    
    context = {
    'title':title,
    'forms':forms,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', context)

def success(request):
    #This part wont validate after the post redirect?
    **if request.method == 'POST':**
        welcome = request.session['f_name']
        email = request.session['email']

        # User Mailing
        subject = f'Welcome to JSG {welcome}'
        message = 'Testing'
        from_email = 'mydev1996@gmail.com'
        recipient_list = [email]

        user_mail = send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            from_email,
            recipient_list,
            fail_silently = False,
            )

        # Admin Mailing
        subject = f'Welcome to JS {welcome}'
        message = 'Testing'

        admin_mail = mail_admins(
            subject,
            message,
            fail_silently = False,
            )

        context = {
            'welcome' : welcome,
        }
    
    else:
        print("error is here")
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'register/success.html', context)
```

Sorry if it's a dumb question as i'm still learning and the hardest part i have in django is moving things from one view to another. I also would love to know if the "Session" is the correct way to moving object post data across views? or is there a more preferable safer way?

Comment: redirects result in **GET** requests, _not_ POST requests...

Comment: okayyyy thats why, is there a way around this then or a best practice solution?

Comment: Why don't you simply send the mail in the first view itself? Let the second view just be there for display, you really don't need to pass any data around for your use case.

Comment: So i'm trying to make the second view display a "success page" so i would need to render an HTML template, is it possible to render multiple templates in one view?